# Dynamically replace specific characters within strings and assign them to new variables

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

I have a bunch of character vectors which I use to download some files (one for each month of the year), for which I have to change the date for every single link manually (at the end of the vector). It looks like this:

```
query_01_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.01.2019&to=31.01.2019"
query_02_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.02.2019&to=28.02.2019"
query_03_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.03.2019&to=31.03.2019"
query_04_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.04.2019&to=30.04.2019"
query_05_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.05.2019&to=31.05.2019"
query_06_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.06.2019&to=30.06.2019"
query_07_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.07.2019&to=31.07.2019"
query_08_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.08.2019&to=31.08.2019"
query_09_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.09.2019&to=30.09.2019"
query_10_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.10.2019&to=31.10.2019"
query_11_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=1277KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.11.2019&to=30.11.2019"
query_12_19 = "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.12.2019&to=31.12.2019"
```

This is already rather tedious for one year, but it becomes a real pain if I want to this for all the following years (let's say until 2030).
Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, in addition to @r2evans answer, consider the reason why you're storing those in different variables, in 99.9% of cases this kind of data is better stored in a vector or list so you can easily fetch the relevant item by index of loop on the elements of your object.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I stored them in a list now, much more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few tricks to make this easy:

1. use of `seq.Date` to generate the first day of each month (it is shown here as `seq` due to the convenience R's S3 methods provide);
2. substract 1 from those to get the last day of the previous months; and
3. join those together with `paste0` after `format`ing them to the dot-separated date format.

```r
## 1
dates <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "month")
dates
#  [1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-06-01" "2018-07-01"
#  [8] "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01"

dates_first <- format(dates[-length(dates)], format = "%d.%m.%Y")
## 2
dates_last  <- format(dates[-1] - 1L, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
dates_last
#  [1] "31.01.2018" "28.02.2018" "31.03.2018" "30.04.2018" "31.05.2018" "30.06.2018" "31.07.2018"
#  [8] "31.08.2018" "30.09.2018" "31.10.2018" "30.11.2018" "31.12.2018"

## 3
paste0(
  "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=",
  dates_first,
  "&to=",
  dates_last)
#  [1] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.01.2018&to=31.01.2018"
#  [2] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.02.2018&to=28.02.2018"
#  [3] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.03.2018&to=31.03.2018"
#  [4] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.04.2018&to=30.04.2018"
#  [5] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.05.2018&to=31.05.2018"
#  [6] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.06.2018&to=30.06.2018"
#  [7] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.07.2018&to=31.07.2018"
#  [8] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.08.2018&to=31.08.2018"
#  [9] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.09.2018&to=30.09.2018"
# [10] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.10.2018&to=31.10.2018"
# [11] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.11.2018&to=30.11.2018"
# [12] "?format=Html&userId=1232&userHash=U127KfIHaiz3ks2gXEgNctA9n8P4c87o1SFcEu2weKpNdupQwmuRaMltEN7&query=ApplicationStatusByJob&from=01.12.2018&to=31.12.2018"
```

(Easily could have been done with `sprintf` or related functions.)